# pafy didn't download successfully. How do I solve it?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pafy

I use this module to download some music, but it downloaded unsuccessfully.

Code:

```py
audio = loop.run_until_complete(ydl.getAudio(name))
ydl.download(audio["stream"], f'{audio["title"]}.mp3')
```

It logged **nothing**...

It can get the pafy stream, but it's "download" method isn't working.